# Hibernate : many ScrollResults to fetch full database (like subquery strategy)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, fetching-strategy

I try to dump to file full database's contents with the least number of requests.

Thus, **How to enable *subquery fetching* with *query.scroll* ?**

### My objects :

I have database like :

```
Employee (1) ------ (0..n) Address
```

Employee class :

```
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
public Set<Address> getAddresses() { ... }
```

Address class :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
public Employee getEmployee() { ... }
```

Java code :

```
     session.createQuery("FROM Employee").scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

### Expected :

When I use *query.find* method, I get :

```
select * from employee
select * from address where employee_id in (select employee_id from employee)
```

But there are OutOfMemoryError on full database.

And when I use *session.scroll*, it use batch fetching :

```
select * from employee
-- and n times :
select * from address where employee_id = ? or employee_id = ? ...
```

Thus, how can I have "query.find*'s queries with *query.scroll*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried something : create 2 *ScrollResult* and mapped relations by myself, replacing hibernate's *PersistentSet*.

It's work ! But I'm not sure it's a *good practice* ... And it take lot of database's temporary memory.

Any advise on this practice ?